# Insert values in second table using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have one table called `[FridgeTemperture]`, when any record inserted it should add one value in the new table `MpSensors`. But records are not being inserted in the new table when a record is inserted.

Error

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table
> 'MpSensors' either identity_insert is set to ON or when a replication
> user is inserting into a not for replication identity column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[FridgeTemperature_INSERT]
    ON [dbo].[FridgeTemperture]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT MpSensors ON;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @fridge_temp varchar(10)

    INSERT INTO MpSensors(fridge_temp)
        VALUES(@fridge_temp)

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT MpSensors OFF;
END    
GO
```

Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MpSensors](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fridge_temp] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FridgeTemperture](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ShopId] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [Fridgetemp] [decimal](4, 2) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `set identity_insert on` if you are not attempting to insert values to the identity column. Also, your current insert statement, if you loose the `set identity_insert`, will simply inside a single null row for any insert statement completed successfully on the `FridgeTemperture` table.
When using triggers, you have access to the records effected by the statement that fired the trigger via the auto-generated tables called `inserted` and `deleted`.
I think you are after something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[FridgeTemperature_INSERT]
   ON  [dbo].[FridgeTemperture]
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO MpSensors(fridge_temp)
   SELECT CAST(Fridgetemp as varchar(10)) 
   FROM inserted

END
```

Though I can't really see any benefit of storing the same value in two different places, and in two different data types.

**Update**

Following our conversation in the comments, you can simply use an update statement  in the trigger instead of an insert statement:

```
UPDATE MpSensors
SET fridge_temp = (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(Fridgetemp as varchar(10)) 
    FROM inserted
    ORDER BY Id DESC
)
```

This should give you the latest record in case you have an insert statement that inserts more than a single record into the `FridgeTemperture` table in a single statement.

Comment: i have one analytics table and one latest table. so when i want to show the dashboard i dont want to get the data from the analytics data by querieng last 1.when the insertion done i want to update the latest table.

Comment: It means you just want to update the second table if records found ?

Comment: yes i have one post api to insert records. while inserted one record in 1 table that same data should be updated in another triggered table.your code is working fine but i wanted to make it updated not new record inserted. every time its getting new record in second table

Comment: "i wanted to make it updated not new record inserted" so you will only have a single record in `MpSensors`? regardless of `ShopId`? Still this makes little sense. You can easily get the last value using a simple query, and with a properly indexed `FridgeTemperture` table this should be a nasty fast query even if the table have millions of rows...

Comment: actually i have many tables like frigetemp, room temp, door status. all latest values should come in one table . so im making 3 triggers so that i can get one single record in different table to fetch data faster to show in my dashboard rather than fetching data from multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SELECT` statement with `CAST` as `[fridge_temp]` is `varchar` in `MpSensors` table in Trigger. Try like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <table_name>
   ON <table_name>
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN    
   INSERT INTO <table_name>(column_name)
   SELECT CAST(column_name AS varchar(10)) 
   FROM inserted    
END
```

The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger table.

Comment: He is missing `inserted` auto-generated table to achieve his goal. It would be better if you explain a bit about the `inserted` table to him.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[FridgeTemperature_INSERT]
   ON [dbo].[FridgeTemperture]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE MpSensors
  SET fridge_temp = CAST(Fridgetemp as varchar(10)) 
  FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: Thats not going to work.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?